# cannot delete the camunda incident

Tags: camunda

I am trying to resolve the incident in camunda using this API https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.11/reference/rest/incident/resolve-incident/

but getting this error. 
{
    "type": "InvalidRequestException",
    "message": "Cannot resolve an incident of type failedExternalTask"
}

Also, I cannot find option in camunda UI.
I would like to know how to resolve the incident and re-trigger the workflow after resolving the incident.

Details  of the Camunda
- Community Edition, container image tag is: "7.11.0"

Comment: You might have found a bug here ...

Answer (score 1):

The incident will be resolved when you increase the number of retries in the corresponding external task. E.g. using the endpoint:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/reference/rest/external-task/put-retries/

This is described here:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/process-engine/incidents/#incident-types